# What is the name of this AC power connector?

Tags: ac, connector, identification, mains, socket

[image]

What is the name of the connector in the picture?
I am not a native English speaker, and I'm having problem searching for this on Banggood.

Comment: It's a combination of the round pin euro connector rated for 240 V, and a flat pin US connector rated for 120 V, usually used for shavers.

Comment: Try "power socket" and maybe some other places besides [BG](https://i.imgur.com/8e3Hvsk.png). In English I'd call it a receptacle but their native language is not English.

Answer (score 1):

That is a snap-in panel mount AC outlet.  It is a combination of a NEMA 1-15 and a Euro Plug Type C.

[According to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#China_GB_2099.1%E2%80%902008_and_GB_1002%E2%80%902008_(Type_A_&_I)) it is commonly used in China.  It is defined in standard GB 1002.  It must be rated for 220VAC.

I found one available on a Chinese site that called it "AC socket PCB 2 pin."

I can't find a simple English name for it.  You'll just have to search Banggood for the description.

---

A search for "AC socket PCB 2 pin" on Banggood found this outlet, which is the full Chinese outlet.

[image]